# Use variable with TemplateView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I used to have my pages in Django defined with functions like this:

```
 def pdf(request):
     return render(request, 'blog/pdf.html', {'title': 'PDF files'})
```

Where I was using a `Title` var for html page title. I started to use a `TemplateView` class for my pages and I'm not sure how to use the same `title` inside of something like this:

```
class About(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/about.html'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
class About(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/about.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(About, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'PDF files'
        return context
```